# Html form open's file in text instead of showing output from Python code

Tags: python, html, forms, openai-api

This form should show the output on current page:

```
<div class="form">
    <form action="QA.py" method="POST" onsubmit="return false; >
        <label for="form-search"></label>
        <input type="text" id="form-search" placeholder="Search code ">

        <!-- BUTTONS -->
        <input type="submit" value="code Search" id="code_search" onclick = "processQuery()">
    </form>

    <p>Answer: </p>
    <p id = 'output'></p>
</div>
```

Instead, it just opens this code here:

```
def main():
  print("Hello,")
  IN = input("query ")
  QT = f"Q: {IN}  ? A:"
  response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="text-davinci-003",
    prompt=QT,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=64,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=["\n\n"]
  )
```

1. User will input query in `form-search` on Html page
2. After clicking submit, the query should go to `QA.py` code
3. In the Python code, input value should be submitted to `IN`
4. After Python provides the output should be displayed in `output`

Instead it just opens `QA.py`.

Comment: What web server are you using? Is it configured to run python files?

Comment: i am runing it on local

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotation mark on the form `OnSubmit`. The resulting javascript error allows the form to submit to the specified action which is your python file.

The Python file will only execute if run on a webserver that is properly configured. It may be that your web server is not configured for Python, or that you are running the html as a local file (ie from disk, not via a web server), and thus your Python file gets served as a file rather than executed.

It would appear you are trying to run a submit through javascript on a button. In which case the form action isn't required. Instead your `processQuery()` function which you haven't shared needs to specify which file to exectue.

Comment: <div class="form">
      <form action="QA.py" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateForm()" >
        <label for="form-search"></label>
        <input type="text" id="form-search" placeholder="Search Boogole or type URL">

       <!-- BUTTONS -->
          <input type="submit" value="Bhugol Search" id="Bhugol_search">
      </form>
        <p>Answer: </p>
        <p id = 'output'></p>
    </div>

I fixed it, 
now there is a different problem it says

"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

I am using Apache server locally

Comment: What is the content of your `validateForm()` function? If that function does not return false the form will be submitted to your QA.py file.